# iTunes not recognizing my iPod touch! (Wierd Glitch)

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipod-touch, jailbreak, ipod

Well, I am using a jailbroken iPod touch 6g and the iTunes isn't recognizing it!

I have tried ever single alternative i could find on internet but had no luck!

The weird part is that whenever i connect the iPod touch to my PC it gets considered as a removable disc but when i turn off the ipod.......just for a split second, my iTunes recognizes my iPod and the again after i turn it on, it gets recognized as an removable disc!

Any solution to this???

I have to restore my iPod....any other way i can find around restoring my iPod?

Comment: can you go to a dfu mode or a safe mode ? what are the things you've tried ?

Comment: I go to recovery mode but iTunes doesnt recognise my ipod

Comment: sometime windows doesn't load the correct driver for iDevices on recovery mode, iTunes won't be able to recognize your iPod. Try the same procedure on a mac (from a friend, or use one of the mac devices displayed in an Apple Store if it's near your)

Comment: Yea...ill give it a try :) Thanks for the advice.....ill have to end up restoring and rejailbreaking!

Comment: happy to help :)